# Google Ad-Manager (client lib PHP) How to list all data under technology?

Tags: php, google-ad-manager

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdManager/v201808/LineItemService/CreateLineItems.php

> for ref, **CreateLineItems.php**

```
    // Target just the Chrome browser.
    $browserTechnology = new Technology();
    $browserTechnology->setId(500072);

    // Create technology targeting.
    $browserTargeting = new BrowserTargeting();
    $browserTargeting->setBrowsers([$browserTechnology]);
    $technologyTargeting = new TechnologyTargeting();
    $technologyTargeting->setBrowserTargeting($browserTargeting);
```

so that ID (500072) is for chrome browser, now where can I get list/table to get other browser IDs. also, I want to target a particular device i.e. desktop only, so how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: found the solution, visit 
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues/542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the V201905 you can use the `PublisherQueryLanguageService` to retrive a list of browser to get your desired mapping:

https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v201905/PublisherQueryLanguageService#browser

Comment: thanks for the answer, it was long ago though. I think I got it back then ..still, your answer can help others :)

Comment: That was my motivation since I was facing the same issue;)